# Blender Rigid body slow on my new MacBook Pro M2

Tags: rigidbody, osx

Why is blender so slow to calculate rigid body physics on my new MacBook Pro m2?
Have 60 cubes falling into a jar as in this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGIga-pruGQ&t=443s and it takes forever for Blender to calculate.

Do I need to adjust setting or something?

Comment: what blender version did you download?

Comment: Im using Blender 3.6

Answer (score 0):

It is weird, I went ahead a downloaded the latest version of Blender, making sure I chose the silicon option. Changed the GPU backend system setting to Metal.
The original file had 65 cubes and 130k Verts and was still lagging.
I then recreated the file from scratch, beveled in the edit tab and managed to reduce the Verts size a lot and now 64 cubes had only 13k Verts and was running in real time.
But even when upping to over 1000 cubes and 200k Verts it was still running pretty good (at 8fps the lowest) compare to under 2fps in the original file.

Can't figure out way. I did use only one material in the new version but the size of the file was double then the original and it still run better